# Different device compatibility depending on account

Tags: google-play-store, accounts, compatibility

I am using the google play store website (play.google.com) on my Android device.  I have 2 accounts.

With one account, the app says "This app is compatible with your device".

But, when I switch accounts and go to the app page again, I get the error "You don't have any devices".

Device compatibility should not dependent on the account, right?  What is going on here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check on https://play.google.com/settings to see which devices are registered on each account. Device compatibility can be either related to the device spec (e.g. Android version, CPU architecture, etc.) and *non-device spec* (e.g. current country based on registered payment methods).

Comment: Is the second Google account registered on your device and usable in PlayStore app on the device? A lot of apps are only available for certain devices, a certain carrier or a certain country.